# Figuring out Yarn application_id for insert statements via JDBC

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive, hadoop-yarn

I am executing an insert query via Hive JDBC client.
The method that I execute is: 
`boolean execute(String sql) throws SQLException` [[this]](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/jdbc/src/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveStatement.java#L264). This is a blocking call.
I understand that after some hops, there will be a Map-Reduce job launched on the Hadoop cluster.

Problem:
Now, as per my requirement, I need to kill the MR job if it does not complete within a stipulated time.
Currently, the only method that I know of killing an MR job is via Yarn, `yarn application -kill application_1428487296152_25597`
OR 
`hadoop job -kill $jobId`.
But in the above case, since I am executing via JDBC, I am neither getting the Yarn app ID, nor the Hadoop Job Id. How should I go about it?

PS: I have a series of MR applications running in a single workflow. The timeout spec. is at a workflow level. Therefore, would require to kill flows on demand.

PPS: I am using version 1.2.1 of Hive-JDBC client.

Comment: [`Statement.setQueryTimeout(int timeout)`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4924)

Comment: I have a series of MR applications running in a single workflow. The timeout spec. is at a workflow level. Therefore, would require to kill flows on demand.